# Listview item animation upon clicking the checkbox

Tags: android, animation, checkbox, android-listview, android-animation

my listview item consists of 3 textview, 1 imageview and Checkbox. When checkbox is checked i'm doing animation so that user should feel like item is sliding up for few milliseconds and it gets disappear.

Here i'm feeling only checkbox is moving but none of the textview or imageview is sliding up. Here is the code of animation

```
OnClickListener CheckboxListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 

             final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.splashfadeout);
                v.startAnimation(animation);
                Handler handle = new Handler();
                handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       mcompletecallback.completePressedItem(cursorHelper.primaryKey);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        animation.cancel();
                    }
                }, 1000);
}
}
```

My anim xml file looks like this, splashfadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```